# What is the difference between callback_group and callback_event when creating a publisher?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The documentation of the Node class defines the create_publisher function as follows:

`create_publisher(msg_type, topic, qos_profile, *, callback_group=None, event_callbacks=None)`

Then, it defines the callback_group as follows: The callback group for the publisher’s event handlers. If None, then the node’s default callback group is used.

Also defines the callback_event as: User-defined callbacks for middleware events.

I understand that the callback_event is a function created by the user. However, I am not sure what the calback_group does.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389211/what-is-the-difference-between-callback_group-and-callback_event-when-creating-a-publisher?/) by [JollyRogers](https://answers.ros.org/users/33294/jollyrogers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2021-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The event callbacks are for middleware Quality of Service events such as a buffer being filled, a publication deadline being missed, or similar. You can see which events are available for publishers in [the documentation here](https://docs.ros2.org/galactic/api/rclcpp/structrclcpp_1_1PublisherEventCallbacks.html).

Callback groups are used to control how the callbacks are called. For example, they can be used to prevent two callbacks being entered at the same time if a multi-threaded executor is used. They are more important to subscribers, which have a callback for when data is received, than publishers, although publishers have QoS event callbacks that are relevant.
Take a look at the [documentation for the `CallbackGroup` object](https://docs.ros2.org/galactic/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1CallbackGroup.html#a137e3cc7ca95c3d986d6a5fff9f397d9), which manages them, for more information about what they are and how to use them.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2021-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JollyRogers](https://answers.ros.org/users/33294/jollyrogers/) on 2021-10-21**:
Thank you for your answer.